# Is there a yeoman command similar to rails destroy

Tags: backbone.js, model-view-controller, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I'm learning to use backbone so I started with the yeoman backbone scaffolding system.

It's similar to everything I know if rails so far... There's a terminal command:

```
$ yo backbone //creates your file tree in your app directory
$ rails new App //creates your file tree in a new directory
```

There's a command for making components of your MVC structure:

```
$ yo backbone:model user //generates the files for a user model
$ rails generate model user //generates the files for a user model
```

But when I go to destroy/undo/rollback/delete the MVC component I run into issues.

```
$ yo ?????
$ rails destroy model user //rolls back the addition
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, we don't have a destroy like in rails. We recommend to use some version control, so that you can easily revert the last change. You can find a discussion on the same on generator repository. As a Team we think that incorporating destroy into yeoman core is complex to maintain.